# i want array filter array by NSPredicate of swift3.0

Tags: arrays, swift3, nspredicateeditor

I have a need right now, This requirement is to use an array of data in another array filter with `NSPredicate`. In Object-C it is works like below：

```
NSArray * arr1 = @[@1,@2,@3]; 

NSArray * arr2 = @[@2,@3,@4,@5];

NSPredicate * filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF IN %@)",arr1]; 

NSArray * filter = [arr2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

By this method, I can get filter,T he elements in this array are not included in the arr1.But I can't find related methods on Swift 3.0. If I can get all of help,I would appreciate it very much

Comment: There's almost never a reason to use `NSArray` in Swift, and `NSPredicate` can be replaced with much simpler designs, most of the time

Comment: As with almost all cases of translation (for both programming languages and human languages), **don't** try to swap out each word for its counterpart. Instead, understand the semantics (the meaning) of the phrase, then translate it into a new phrase that fits the new language best. It's not necessarily similar at all to the source phrase, but it yields a much better outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can simply use [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641239-filter) no need to use `NSPredicate`.

```
let array1 = [1,2,3]
let array2 = [2,3,4,5]
let filterArray = array2.filter { !array1.contains($0) }
print(filterArray) // [4, 5]
```

**Edit:** As @Alexander suggested batter if you use set also with `array1`.

```
let array1 = [1,2,3,2,3]
let set = Set(array1)
let array2 = [2,3,4,5]
let filterArray = array2.filter { !set.contains($0) }
print(filterArray)
```

Comment: @chenbo Note, for any non-trivial array size, it's MUCH better to first convert `array1` into a Set. It'll speed up this O(N^2) algorithm to O(N), making for a huge improvement in performance.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Good suggestion but I think `contains` will not go further if it matches the first one it will return and not checked for remaining elements.

Comment: It does do that, but that doesn't at all reduce the computational complexity. Assuming a uniform distribution, in which the desired element is equally likely to be in any position of the array, on average, it'll be found halfway (some earlier, some later, but halfway on average). That's `array2.count / 2` searching operations, repeated `array2.count` times (one round per element of `array2`, so you get a total time complexity of `O(array2.count / 2 * array2.count)`, which is `O(N^2)`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Edited answer for that, good explanation :)

Comment: "`Array(Set(array1))`" wut ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Does it looks batter now.